# Positive points on a shifted integer lattice

Tags: lattices

Suppose I have a shifted integer lattice, i.e. some origin $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, some vectors $\vec{b}_1, ..., \vec{b}_n \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ which generate the (shifted) lattice $L = \{ \vec{v} + \sum_i c_i \vec{b}_i | c_i \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Is there any procedure/algorithm to determine the $c_i's$ which give a point that has all positive coordinates?